# Empty Array Vs Dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I am just learning Swift and found the concept of Empty Array and Empty Dictionary. I could not dig it down with the simple examples, when to choose it and what are the benefits? Your help would be appreciated.
`let emptyArray = [String]()
let emptyDictionary = [String: Float]()`

If the constant can be empty then why to use array?

Comment: Are you planning to add data to them later? For your code as written (using `let`) they're **both** almost entirely useless, because you can't add anything to them and you can't really do anything with an empty collection.

Comment: So what would be the situation that I can use emptyArray or emptyDictionary?

Comment: I can't think of any situation where I would want to use either one by themselves. They're both only useful if you put things inside them, and that depends entirely on what you want to put inside them and what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to "dig down". An empty thing is just a thing that is empty. Emptiness has no effect on the thingness of a thing. For example:

- An empty honey jar is a jar with no honey in it.
- An empty bank account is a bank account with no money in it.
- An empty string is a string with no characters in it.
- An empty array is an array with no elements in it.
- An empty dictionary is a dictionary with no key-value pairs in it.

The emptiness of a string does not make the string less of a string; it just happens to be empty. The emptiness of a bank account does not make the bank account less of a bank account. You do not say: how do I choose between between an empty bank account and an empty string? So you do not say: how do I choose between an empty array and an empty dictionary.

So if you don't understand the difference between an array and a dictionary, that is one thing. But the use of "empty" in your question adds nothing whatever to the mix.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your response.
But one thing I am still confused is I can use emptyHoneyJar to refill it, empty bankAccount to deposit on it and so on however can I use emptyArray or emptyDictionary to add values (may be key value pair) in it? If so, can it be initialized as constant?

Comment: You can initialize an empty array or dictionary as a constant but if it is a constant you can never put anything inside it, so it isn’t obvious why you would do such a thing. If it is a variable, not a constant, then the analogy holds.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It just depends on what you're trying to do. These variables don't just exist in isolation. If they did, they would be useless and you should remove them.

Are you calling an API that requires an array? Well then you would pass it an array.

Are you calling an API that requires a dictionary? Well then you would pass it a dictionary.

Comment: array -> array, dictionary -> dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is an unordered structure of data. Data is accessed by a key-value.

Array is an ordered structure of data. Data is accessed by location.

```
dict["aKey"] = CGFloat(1)

array.append("Thursday")
```

The dictionary grows by adding keys and assigning value.

The array grows by appending value to the end.